# Why does capistrano puts my Rails app in Releases folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano

After fighting through a lot of issues, I was able to deploy my Rails app ... but now the whole Rails directory structure is in the /var/www/-myappname-/releases/-datetimestamp- folder

I expected the app to get put into /var/www/-myappname- so that the routing would work?  What am I missing here?  Did I forget a step?

Answer (score 2):

This is done for couple of reasons

- app doesn't go down during deploy (as some files would be overwritten while app is still running in the same dir)
- so you can easily and quickly rollback in case of fuckup on deploy

Also, current release should be symlinked to `/var/www/-myappname-/current` and that's there your server should point to.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I'm very new to this level of server interaction -- how do I point my server to that directory so that, for example, went I visit www.-myappname-.com the app loads?

Comment: The guide you followed for capistrano should cover that, I don't have any example to look at at the moment (hosting everything on heroku)